# jQuery passing var to hidden form input

Tags: jquery

How would I pass a jQuery var i.e.`$.cookie("FirstName"` to a `FORM` input value? This what I've put together so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) { 
    //console.debug($.cookie("FirstName"));
        $("#FirstName").value($.cookie("FirstName"));
    //console.debug($.cookie("LastName"));
        $("#LastName").value($.cookie("LastName"));
    //console.debug($.cookie("Email"));
        $("#Email").value($.cookie("Email"));
...
```

**FORM**

```
<FORM>
<input name="FirstName" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="LastName" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="Email" type="hidden" value="">
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `name` because you didnt have `id` for your fields .So it would be like

```
$("input[name='FirstName']").val($.cookie("FirstName"));
$("input[name='LastName']").val($.cookie("LastName"));
```

Or you can give the `id` to those input tags like

```
<input name="FirstName" type="hidden" value="" id="FirstName">
```

But before that please try to `search/do` something not to **ask**.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='FirstName']").val($.cookie("FirstName"));
```

use .val() in jquery not .value

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **name** because you didnot have **id**

```
  $("input[name='FirstName']").val($.cookie("FirstName"));
  $("input[name='LastName']").val($.cookie("LastName"));
  $("input[name='Email']").val($.cookie("Email"));
  .....
```

use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** at the place of value

Answer (score 1):

you dont have any such `id` in your html, use `name` instead with [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like:

```
$("input[name='FirstName']").val($.cookie("FirstName"));
```